# Printing multiple lines at the same time C++

Tags: c++, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void slowPrint(unsigned long speed, const char *s)
{
   int i = 0;
   while(s[i]!=0)
   {
      cout << s[i++];
      cout.flush();
      Sleep(speed);
   }
}
int main()
{
      char choice;

      cout << "================================================================================\n";
      slowPrint(80, " \"Words being said\"\n\n");
      cout << "================================================================================\n";
      cin >> choice;

      return 0;
}
```

So I was wondering if I could somehow print line 19-21 at the same time. Instead of just having the first "===..." print out, then the slow typing from line 20, and lastly the end of the code.

Or is there a way to even output both of the "===" bars and then slow typing the line between them.

Please help if you can!

Thanks.

(You might be confused on how this is worded but it's hard to explain. I can try and explain more in depth if needed.)

Comment: Well, you could use something like [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) to print both outer lines and then position it to print the middle line.

Comment: I'm still an amateur to C++ so I am unfamiliar with this command. Do you know how you would use this in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to print fancy things to a terminal screen is to use escape sequences. If you've ever wondered how your keyboard tells your computer about arrow key inputs, even though there are no explicit ASCII keys for those operations, escape sequences are the answer.

Escape sequences are begun with the escape character, or ASCII value 27. To move the cursor up, you need something along the following lines:

```
char esc(27); //You need to initialize the escape character by calling its ASCII value
std::cout << esc << "[1A" // This line moves the cursor up.
          << "\r"; // This line moves the cursor all the way back to the left.
```

So, in order to get the output you want, try the following for the body of your main:

char choice, esc(27);

```
std::cout << "================================================================================\n\n"
          << "================================================================================"
          << esc << "[1A\r";
slowPrint(1, " \"Words being said\"\n\n");
std::cin >> choice;

return 0;
```

There are many escape sequences that can be used to control your terminal. For instance, try printing the following escape sequence followed by some other text.

```
"[1;31m"
```

See the following link for more escape sequences.

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

Comment: I was messing with this and saw that I couldn't get it to print a certain line, 3 lines above from where it's supposed to be. Like, I would be able to print the borders first before inputting text between.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I'll give it a shot. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hmm, well I still seem to get the same thing. "Words being said" is still being outputted after the 2 "===" bars. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Does it work for you? As in, printing "Words being said" inside the two bars.

Comment: It is likely something that has to do with being on windows. I just read [this page](http://www.nthelp.com/40/ansiNT.htm) which has instructions for getting windows to accept ANSI commands. ANSI are the rules which set the standard for ASCII and the C programming language.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that I'm on windows. I'll mess with that page later. Thanks for all the help!